# How to add an external URL to new Podio item created using Podio PHP API?

Tags: php, podio

As mentioned in below example:

```
$newItem = PodioItem::create($app_id, array(
    'fields' => array(
        "name" => "John", 
        "company-profile" => "<a href='http://example.com/' target='_blank'>View Profile</a>")));
```

As I have applied an external link to `company-profile` by the name of `View Profile`, but I will not get the error: `500 Internal Server Error - PodioBadRequestError`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Go and read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for better help and a cleaner question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `company-profile` is Podio field of type `link`.

If that's true, then it should be handled a bit differently. In terms of Podio it's called `embed`, and you can read what it is and how to create one here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/embeds

Comment: Thanks! Yes you are right , i added a link using embed but the link is not clickable because of podio default detail link on each row in podio app listing. How can i enable my link to clickable on podio app listings page.

Comment: I didn't get that, what link you are trying to embed?